# Laravel: One File with Two Classes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

In Laravel, is it possible to have one file with two classes? E.g.:

In app/Portal.php, I have two classes:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Portal
{
    public static function state($abbreviation)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class PaymentLogs extends Model
{
    // ...
}
```

Is that possible?

If yes, how can I call each class from a controller? For example, if the PaymentLogs class is in app/Portal.php, this won't work:

```
\App\PaymentLogs::create();
```

How can I call the PaymentLogs class in from app/Http/Controllers/PortalController.php and the state() method from the Portal class?

Comment: It is possible, but it wont autoload in other files I believe. So unless you are only referencing the class inside the same file, better to separate it out. See https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Thanks Kurt, I'll take your advice.